# Java program failing on specific test case

Tags: java, algorithm

I wrote a java program that does basically what wordle does. Given 2 3x3 rows, for example

```
// Answer
AAA
BBB
CCC
// Guess
AYY
AAA
ZZZ
```

If the guess matches the answer (in this case index [0][0]), mark it as "green"
If the guess does NOT match the answer at the exact position, but it IS valid (for example A at answer[1][0] does not match guess[1][0] but is an answer at guess[0][1]) would be counted as "yellow"

Here is the code I currently have. It works in this test case and all other test cases except for one. I can't seem to catch my error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// Currently test case 6 not working

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner io = new Scanner(System.in);
        int green = 0, yellow = 0;
        char[][] answer = new char[3][3];
        char[][] guess = new char[3][3];
        {
            String tempString = io.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                answer[0][i] = tempString.charAt(i);
            }
            tempString = io.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                answer[1][i] = tempString.charAt(i);
            }
            tempString = io.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                answer[2][i] = tempString.charAt(i);
            }

            tempString = io.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                guess[0][i] = tempString.charAt(i);
            }
            tempString = io.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                guess[1][i] = tempString.charAt(i);
            }
            tempString = io.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                guess[2][i] = tempString.charAt(i);
            }
            //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(answer));
            //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(guess));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (answer[i][j] == guess[i][j]) {
                    answer[i][j] = (char) -1;
                    guess[i][j] = (char) -1;
                    green++;
                }
            }
        }



        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (answer[i][j] != guess[i][j]) {
                    char needToFind = guess[i][j];

                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                        for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
                            if (answer[k][l] == needToFind) {
                                yellow++;
                                guess[i][j] = (char) -1;
                                answer[k][l] = (char) -1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //System.out.println("-----2"); debug here don't mind me
                    //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(answer));
                    //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(guess));
                    //System.out.println(yellow);


                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(green);
        System.out.println(yellow);
    }

}
/*
plan
    Get input using 2d arrays
    Create 2 matrix arrays: answer and guess
    Get the values into the array
    Use for loop that loops 9 times
    If the value at answer is the same at same index in guess, green++

    Use another for loop 9 times, if the indexes are NOT the same (and is not -1), then find if another of the same value exists in another index, if so, change the answer index into -1 and yellow++;

*/
```

I'm not currently worried that much about the speed, it performs about as I expect for the simple implementation I've made.

Comment: "_**for example A at answer[1][0] does not match guess[1][0] but is an answer at guess[0][1]**_" - shouldn't be the other way around? (guess[1][0]) does not match answer[1][0] but is an answer at answer[0][1])

Comment: I think I just simplified your logic. My answer seems to work. I can add comment to the code if you require an explanation of the nested if/else logic.

Comment: [mcve]: tell us which test is failing. That is also the way how YOU approach such issues. You think about all the different test scenarios, and then you start with the most simple one. And every time you get an unexpected result, you add print statements so that you understand WHY your code isnt doing what you think it should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

Pseudocode:

```
IF letter at CURRENT_INDEX -> "green"
ELSEIF letter anywhere in string array -> "yellow"
ELSE (not found) -> "red"
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] guess = {"AYY","AAA","ZZZ"};
    String[] answer = {"AAA","BBB","CCC"};
        
    Stream<String> aWords = Arrays.asList(answer).stream(); // "AAABBBCCC"
    String aFlat = aWords.collect(Collectors.joining());

    String [][] color = new String[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            String guessLetter = Character.toString((guess[i]).charAt(j));
            if (Character.toString(answer[i].charAt(j)).equals(guessLetter)) {
                color[i][j] = "green";
            } else if (aFlat.contains(guessLetter)) {
                color[i][j] = "yellow";
            } else {
                color[i][j] = "red";
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output of the program is this:

```
[
  [green, red, red], // for "AYY" vs "AAA"
  [yellow, yellow, yellow], // for "AAA" vs "BBB"
  [red, red, red] // for "ZZZ" vs "CCC"
]
```

The only letter that matches the letter at the current index is `guess[0][0]`. `guess[0][1]` and `guess[0][2]` are red because the letter `Y` cannot be found in the flattened `aFlat` string.

`guess [1][x]` is all yellows because the letter `A` is found on the flattened `aFlat` string, but not in the correct index location in the answer array.

Lastly, `guess[2][x]` is red because the letter `Z` is not found anywhere on the flattened `aFlat` string.